# How to create tasks with shared lock in celery?

Tags: python, api, celery, synchronous

I am new to both python and celery, and not quite sure how to define my problem regarding celery.

I will try to explain my problem with an example;

Lets say there is a system where users buy tickets for events. Each event has a fixed cap of tickets(10). Requests to API is synchronous and buy requests return a success or fail depending of the event's capacity. Obviously this might create a race-condition for that resource.

There are two solutions I could think of:

1. Somehow add a database constraint that will block the insert requests when event is full.(Could not find any applicable solution btw)
2. Add a sequential task queue for buy ticket events. This way it is ensured that there will be no race. However since I am waiting for the API response, with enough load it might take ages for the task to be executed, if there is only 1 queue. To reduce this waiting time, I have to implement a event-id-based queue mechanism, where each event has its own sequential queue created dynamically, and will have its own consumer. Once the event is full consumer should be dissolved. Is there any way to achieve this with **celery**?

Thanks.

Comment: do you know the event-id names upfront or it is generated at runtime?

Comment: @dassum once event is available, it has an event-id even though it has 0 registrant.